# what is the portable equivalent to linux`s signal.siginterrupt in python?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, signals, portability

I have this Linux centric code that I would like to get to run on Windows, too:

```
class SignalObject:
    MAX_TERMINATE_CALLED = 3

    def __init__(self, shutdown_event):
        self.terminate_called = 0
        self.shutdown_event = shutdown_event


def default_signal_handler(signal_object, exception_class, signal_num, current_stack_frame):
    signal_object.terminate_called += 1
    signal_object.shutdown_event.set()
    if signal_object.terminate_called >= signal_object.MAX_TERMINATE_CALLED:
        raise exception_class()


def init_signal(signal_num, signal_object, exception_class, handler):
    handler = functools.partial(handler, signal_object, exception_class)
    signal.signal(signal_num, handler)
    signal.siginterrupt(signal_num, False)


def init_signals(shutdown_event, int_handler, term_handler):
    signal_object = SignalObject(shutdown_event)
    init_signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_object, KeyboardInterrupt, int_handler)
    init_signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_object, TerminateInterrupt, term_handler)
    return signal_object
```

Specifically, it bombs out on `signal.siginterrupt(signal_num, False)` and gives me this traceback:

```
ERROR:root:  0:00.000 MAIN                 Exception: module 'signal' has no attribute 'siginterrupt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Documents/GitHub/magnetfeld-kabel/util/bin/magnetic_cable_interactive.py", line 186, in main
    init_signals(main_ctx.shutdown_event, default_signal_handler, default_signal_handler)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mptools-0.2.0-py3.7.egg\mptools\_mptools.py", line 115, in init_signals
    init_signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_object, KeyboardInterrupt, int_handler)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mptools-0.2.0-py3.7.egg\mptools\_mptools.py", line 110, in init_signal
    signal.siginterrupt(signal_num, False)
AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'siginterrupt'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.3.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Documents/GitHub/magnetfeld-kabel/util/bin/magnetic_cable_interactive.py", line 221, in <module>
    main(die_in_secs)
  File "C:/Users/Documents/GitHub/magnetfeld-kabel/util/bin/magnetic_cable_interactive.py", line 186, in main
    init_signals(main_ctx.shutdown_event, default_signal_handler, default_signal_handler)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mptools-0.2.0-py3.7.egg\mptools\_mptools.py", line 115, in init_signals
    init_signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_object, KeyboardInterrupt, int_handler)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mptools-0.2.0-py3.7.egg\mptools\_mptools.py", line 110, in init_signal
    signal.siginterrupt(signal_num, False)
AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'siginterrupt'
```

How can I change that to run on both Windows and Linux? I googled for equivalents and found nothing.

Comment: First of all before asking a question, at least read the docs.  According to [signal — Set handlers for asynchronous events](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html), the replacement is ```signal.SIGBREAK``` Interrupt from keyboard (CTRL + BREAK). 
Availability: Windows.

Comment: @itprorh66 https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html this is the doc you cite, right? I did read it. it also mentions signal.SIGINT, without a UNIX or Windows availability, and thus (?) more portable. I want a solution that works on Windows and Unix, not one or the other. 

Furthermore, the problem does not seem to be with signal.SIGINT but rather with signal.siginterrupt, as can be seen in the traceback - right? (I am not sure, this is my interpretation of the traceback.)

Please don't play the "read the docs" card without a better reason then this.